# removeAll not removing at next validate?

Tags: java, swing

Can someone explain why the following doesn't work as I expect?

Pressing the button 'should' result in the display only containing the (empty) JScrollPane, ie the input field and button should disappear. However they stay until the component is resized...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cp.add(new JScrollPane(panel));

    Component textField = new JTextField("i am input");
    JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("i am pressy")
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // this is already on the EDT
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.revalidate();
        }
    });

    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Thanks for your help. p.

Comment: Try `panel.repaint()` instead?

Comment: Good [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When updating a visible GUI the code should be:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed, this appears to be one of them
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`revalidate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) method marks components as needing to be laid out, but until something triggers `repaint()` you won't see any change. Resizing the parent window is one such trigger; switching applications is another. In this previous [version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5812981/3), note how `setSize()` on the panel obviates the need for `repaint()`. Similarly, this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) changes the layout in `resetGame()`.

The article [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) goes into more detail.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812002 */
public class RevalidateTest {

    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // default FlowLayout
    private static JTextField text = new JTextField("Text field");
    private static JButton clear = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(reset);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
    private static JButton reset = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Reset") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(text);
            panel.add(clear);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });

    static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(clear);
        frame.add(panel); // default BorderLayout center
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [`DynamicLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750068/java-swing-how-to-change-gui-dynamically/5751044#5751044).

Comment: but then, which sane application code would ever call setSize ;-) It's just another trigger which queues a component for repaint, so better stick to the direct path than the deviation.

Comment: @kleopatra: Quite right; just an example meant to illuminate the plumbing. Updating…

Answer (score 2):

You can execute `panel.repaint()` as specified in the comment by @Jeremy, however, the UI will still change when you resize the window. The reason being that the removal of the elements from the JPanel will cause the panel to resize.  A repaint operation will not cause the panel to resize until the JFrame rechecks its layout (as happens on a window resize).

To make sure that the layout is correctly layed out on a change, you can call `frame.validate()`.  This operation will cause the JFrame to revalidate itself and all child components, which is the same operation that is taking place during a window resize event.  To execute this method in your code you would need to change `JFrame frame` to final, i.e.,

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
```

Comment: I don't think the removal triggers resizing; I think resizing triggers `repaint()` via the parent window's `ComponentListener`. Switching applications works too, via the window's `WindowListener`. Also, I can't reproduce your `frame.validate()` result unless I also change a size, location, or layout of some component.

Comment: @trashgod whether or not you see an additional resize (aka: Kris' "layout correctly laid out") depends on whether or not panel has a parent which is validationRoot (below the top-level). To be entirely sure the layout is re-evaluated in all of the top-level container, validating that container (which is also the top-most validationRoot) is the way to go

Comment: no need for for a (final or otherwise) reference to the frame - SwingUtilities.windowForComponent is your friend :-)