# How to have a java gui transition from one gui to another

Tags: java, swing, runtime

I am programming a gui in java and it has some buttons one of these buttons is options.  I would like to have it so when you click on options it changes the gui to my options gui instead of opening it in another window.

How can I do this?

Comment: i am not sure what gui kit u are using, but if u are using swing, its as simple as replacing your old panel with new panel in the parent contianer

Answer (score 6):

[`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654926/implementing-back-forward-buttons-in-swing/5655843#5655843), is a good choice. Alternatively, you can just `remove()` and `revalidate()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812002/removeall-not-removing-at-next-validate/5812981#5812981).