# How can I refresh or reload the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am doing project using Java and in that I need to reload whole `JFrame` after clicking particular button on that `JFrame`. How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'refresh'?  Is it 'return all components to the state they were when first put in the frame', 'change the components', something else?

Comment: are you add/remove JComponent on Runtime, or change Size, needed to re-layout...,

Comment: what exactly you are doing with JFrame. Kindly elobrate it. ?

Comment: This question is completely unanswerable as written. Can you share the necessary detail?

Comment: There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812002/removeall-not-removing-at-next-validate/5812981#5812981) that may get you started.

Comment: Yet it has been answered, and at least one of the answers was helpful. So the question wasn't entirely useless, was it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

If it still doesn't work then after completing the above step try

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: -1 for updateComponentTreeUI: that is nearly **always** the wrong thingy to do (it's re-setting the ui-delegates) when the most probable goal is merely reloading the data.

Comment: _reload frame_ isn't a technical term and whatever it's supposed to  mean, updateComponentTree is **NOT** the answer. Actually, the question as-is is way too unspecific to be answerable, so voted to close

Comment: Well, so *what* is the answer, then? The updateComponentTreeUI call does the job.

Comment: @foo use whatever works. You can completely ignore anyone who says "don't do X" without offering a counter solution.

This is the only solution that worked for me. The other suggestions of close and re-showing the frame are assinine.

Answer (score 4):

just use
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
I've had this problem with JLabels with images, and this solved it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short code that might help.

```
    <yourJFrameName> main = new <yourJFrameName>();    

    main.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
```

where...

> main.setVisible(true);

will run the JFrame again.

> this.dispose();

will terminate the running window.

Comment: The question is about reloading the frame (in situ), not showing the frame. The setVisible does not show the frame *again*, it just shows or hides the frame depending on the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I also faced the same problem, but some how I solved it.

```
public class KitchenUserInterface {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel main_panel, northpanel , southpanel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton nextOrder;
    private JList list;

    private static KitchenUserInterface kitchenRunner ;

    public void setList(String[] order){
        kitchenRunner.frame.dispose();
        kitchenRunner.frame.setVisible(false);
        kitchenRunner= new KitchenUserInterface(order);

    }

    public KitchenUserInterface getInstance() {
        if(kitchenRunner == null) {
            synchronized(KitchenUserInterface.class) {
                if(kitchenRunner == null) {
                    kitchenRunner = new KitchenUserInterface();
                }
            }
        }


        return this.kitchenRunner;
    }

    private KitchenUserInterface() {


        frame = new JFrame("Lullaby's Kitchen");
        main_panel = new JPanel();
        main_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(main_panel);



        northpanel = new JPanel();
        northpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        label = new JLabel("Kitchen");

        northpanel.add(label);


        main_panel.add(northpanel , BorderLayout.NORTH);


        frame.setSize(500 , 500 );
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private KitchenUserInterface (String[] order){
        this();
        list = new JList<String>(order);
        main_panel.add(list , BorderLayout.CENTER);

        southpanel = new JPanel();
         southpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         nextOrder = new JButton("Next Order Set");
         nextOrder.addActionListener(new OrderUpListener(list));
         southpanel.add(nextOrder);
         main_panel.add(southpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KitchenUserInterface dat = kitchenRunner.getInstance();
        try{

        Thread.sleep(1500);
        System.out.println("Ready");
        dat.setList(OrderArray.getInstance().getOrders());
        }
        catch(Exception event) {
            System.out.println("Error sleep");
            System.out.println(event);
        }


        }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

You should use this code

```
this.setVisible(false); //this will close frame i.e. NewJFrame

new NewJFrame().setVisible(true); // Now this will open NewJFrame for you again and will also get refreshed
```

Comment: bad question attract bad answers (that's why suggested to close the question - unsuccessfully ;-) *NO* - whatever the real problem in the question, creating a new frame is *NOT* the solution. You wouldn't tear down your house just because it needs some new paint, would you?

Comment: @kleopatra No he won't.