# Reinitializing my JPanel after pressing a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i have a Jframe which has some panels as instance variables and one of the panels is a grid board (i am implementing Lines of action game). After my game ends I have a button "Play again"  which i want to reinitialize my board panel. I tried a lot of things like removing my panel from the content pane and re-initializing it, but nothing worked so far. Here are some of the things i tried (i didn't try them all at once )

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements  MouseListener{

JLabel l = new JLabel();
Panel1 Boards;
Panel2 newGame;
Panel3 winner;
Point lastCheckerSelected;
Board game = new Board();
    public Frame() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Lines Of Action");
    setBounds(290, 350, 1000, 700);
    setLayout(null);
   winner=new Panel3(); 
    winner.playAgain.addMouseListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(winner);

    Boards= new Panel1();

     getContentPane().add(Boards);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
            "E:\\background0213.jpg"));
    l.setBounds(0 ,0 ,  1000 , 700);
    getContentPane().add(l);
    validate(); 
    newGame=new Panel2();
    newGame.b.addMouseListener(this);
  getContentPane().add(newGame);

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
          Boards.x[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
          Boards.y[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
      }
  }

}
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(newGame.b)) {
           Boards.setVisible(true);
           newGame.setVisible(false);
           game=new Board();
     }
if(this.game.getWinner()==1) {
    winner.setVisible(true);
    winner.whiteWins.setVisible(true);
}
if(this.game.getWinner()==2) {
    winner.setVisible(true);
    winner.greywins.setVisible(true);
}
if(e.getSource().equals(winner.playAgain)) {
            //this.getContentPane().remove(Boards);
        //  this.game= new Board();                                          
        //  Boards = new Panel1();      
        //  this.getContentPane().add(Boards);
            //Boards.setVisible(true);
        //  validate();
        //  Boards.repaint();


        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

I still cant make my new panel appear  ( removing the Boards panel from the content pane makes it disappear which is good but the new one does not appear)
here is my panel =1 that contains the board

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel  {
JButton[][] x = new JButton[8][8];
JButton[][] y=new JButton[8][8];
Graphics g;
public Panel1() {
    setBounds(0, 30 ,400 ,400); 
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
    setOpaque(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            x[i][j] = new JButton();
            x[i][j].setSize(50, 50);
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0)) {
                x[i][j].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY.darker());
            //  x[i][j].setBackground(new Color(111,89,81,150));
            }
            else {
                // Color.OPAQUE = 2;
                x[i][j].setBackground(Color.red.darker().darker());
            //  x[i][j].setBackground(new Color(223,37,32,150));
            }

            x[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            add(x[i][j]);
        }
    }
for(int i = 0; i < 8 ;i++){
    for(int j=0;j < 8;j++){
        y[i][j]=new JButton();
    x[i][j].add(y[i][j]);   
    //  y[i][j].setSize(100,100);

    //  y[i][j].setEnabled(false);
    //  y[i][j].setOpaque(false);
    //  y[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
//      y[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);
        y[i][j].setVisible(false);

    }
}
for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
//  y[0][i].setOpaque(true);
    y[0][i].setBackground(Color.white);
    y[0][i].setEnabled(true);
    y[0][i].setVisible(true);
//  y[7][i].setOpaque(true);
    y[7][i].setBackground(Color.white);
    y[7][i].setEnabled(true);
    y[7][i].setVisible(true);

}
for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
//  y[i][0].setOpaque(true);
    y[i][0].setEnabled(true);
    y[i][0].setBackground(new Color(102,125,153));
    y[i][0].setVisible(true);
//  y[i][7].setOpaque(true);
    y[i][7].setEnabled(true);
    y[i][7].setBackground(new Color(102,125,153));
    y[i][7].setVisible(true);
}
//  addMouseListener(this);
    setVisible(false);
}




}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more and clear code please?

Comment: What happens when you try each one? Also, what happens if you try each one and then resize the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
if(e.getSource().equals(winner.playAgain)) 
{
   Boards.removeAll();
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}
```

I don't think you need to create a new `Panel1` instance.

Comment: this removes my board also which is not what i really want :(

Comment: What components do you have in that JPanel?

Comment: public class Panel1 extends JPanel  {
 JButton[][] x = new JButton[8][8];
 JButton[][] y=new JButton[8][8];

Comment: Only buttons? Don't you have listeners etc? Can you give us some clear code from `Panel1`? I am trying to suggest a method to manually reset your panel's state to its default.

Comment: ahhh i could manually reset it god-.-  i will try dont know why i never though of that xD i was just focusing on reinitializing it and making it work

Comment: worked xD thx for the idea dont know how it didnt occur to me to just manually rebuild the board :D

Answer (score 1):

Try these four together. Need to see more of your code to make sure this work.

```
if(e.getSource().equals(winner.playAgain)) {
    this.getContentPane().remove(Boards);
    Boards = new Panel1();
    this.getContentPane().add(Boards);
    this.invalidate();
    this.validate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: if there a difference between revalidate and validate ?
i cannot type this.revalidate as it say  its undefined for type frame oO              and it doesnt work with validate :( it still removes the old board but i cannot see a new board so i can play again

Comment: You can (re-)validate a `JComponent`, such as `JPanel`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812981/230513).

Comment: @user2227557 You're using `JFrame`? Then there are no `revalidate`. `invalidate` it and then `validate` it instead. Sometimes you need to add `repaint`.

Answer (score 1):

> i have a Jframe which has some panels as instance variables and one of
>   the panels is a grid board (i am implementing Lines of action game).
>   After my game ends I have a button "Play again" which i want to
>   reinitialize my board panel. I tried a lot of things like removing my
>   panel from the content pane and re-initializing it, but nothing worked
>   so far.

I think that [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is best of choices

Answer (score 0):

After the components are made visible in the screen, if you remove and add components, then you have to call `Component.repaint()` or `Component.validate()` to call the repainting again. Do this inside your `actionPerformed()` of your `playAgainButton()`