# Adding a jTextArea to JPanel from within the Panel

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So, I am creating a new `Canvas (JPanel)` class: `Canvas canvas = new Canvas();` and then I am calling a method on that class: `canvas.addTextBox();`

Now, from within this Canvas class, I want to add a new jTextArea to the Canvas. I tried using the code below but it isn't showing up. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
class Canvas extends JPanel {

    public Canvas() {
        this.setOpaque(true);
        //this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void addTextBox() {
        final JTextArea commentTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        commentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        commentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        commentTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        commentTextArea.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Full Code**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class UMLEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new UMLWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class UMLWindow extends JFrame {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UMLWindow() {
        addMenus();
    }
    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(canvas);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenuItem newTextBox = new JMenuItem("New Text Box");
        newTextBox.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        newTextBox.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        newTextBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                canvas.addTextBox();
            }
        });

        menubar.add(newTextBox);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class Canvas extends JPanel {

    public Canvas() {
        this.setOpaque(true);
        //this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void addTextBox() {
        final JTextArea commentTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        commentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        commentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        commentTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        commentTextArea.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to add it to the panel. What you have now is only creating the JTextArea along with some setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addTextBox` method only creates a `JTextArea`. It never adds it to the `JPanel`

You will need to add the following line to `addTextBox` method:

```
add( commentTextArea );
```

In case the `JFrame` which contains your components is already visible on screen when the `addTextBox` method is called, you need to invalidate the container as well. Simply add

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: Do I have to notify anything that a JTextArea has been added? This works but it only shows up when I resize/move the JFrame

Comment: @Harry: You'll need to `(re-)validate()` the enclosing container and possibly `repaint()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812981/230513).

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Why `invalidate();` in update? Validate works (but I'm  not familiar with validate() at all, just tested). Also setting a bounds on the JTextArea worked.

Comment: @Harry See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510125/1076463. I basically mark the container as invalid because a component has been added, so the layout must be refreshed. And I then trigger a repaint

Comment: So does this mean you have to validate(); before repainting? If I use invalide() and then repaint() is does the same as before, only shows up when I resize the window

Comment: @Harry Perhaps it was revalidate() and repaint() instead of invalidate() and repaint().