# How to make JComboBox set paticular elements visible and other notvisible

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Could someone tell me how to do this? Ive tried by putting the element1.setVisible(true) in actionListener but it does nothing.

Comment: But do i have to out setVisible(false) in the part i created the element? And then have another setVisible(true) in the actionListener?

Comment: Can you paste the code that you've been using?

Answer (score 1):

If `element1` was added *after* the initial calls to `pack()` and `set visible()`, you will have to `revalidate()`, and possibly `repaint()`, the enclosing container. A more extensive examination of the problem is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812002/230513).