# How can I you dynamically rearrange items in a gridlayout using java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dynamic, grid-layout

I need to rearrange items that are in my `GridLayout` so when a `JButton` is created dynamically, that the footer (i.e. `JLabel`) stays at the bottom of the grid, and the dynamically created button goes right above the footer.

Is this possible? If so can I see an example, please?

My grid currently is a

```
new GridLayout(intIndex, 1);
```

where `intIndex` is incremented every time a dynamic element is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a footer, you probably want to use `BorderLayout` and keep the footer down at the bottom with `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. Then put your component with the `GridLayout` in the center with `BorderLayout.CENTER`. This way, your footer will always remain at the bottom and it won't interfere with the content, which you're now free to change to use any layout manager without affecting the footer.

This should be a good fix if your footer spans across the whole bottom, but if you're trying to make some sort of small footer in the bottom corner, then it'll be a little more difficult, but either way I'd suggest trying to keep the footer separate from the content.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and I didn't even think of this! The only problem I'm having is trying to "repack" (by using pack() after I added the item to the layout). It will repack just not to the new size. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you're adding components directly to a `JFrame` or some heavyweight container you don't need to call `pack()`. What component is not sizing correctly for you? Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: When I add a new panel to the gridlayout in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, the JFrame kind of "overlaps" the previous panel and I figured pack would just resize the jframe to the appropriate size.

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750068/java-swing-how-to-change-gui-dynamically/5751044#5751044).

Comment: @Dennis Martinez: Now you've got a different problem! Fortunately it's a common one - you should be able to find several posts that discuss dynamically adding UI components - check those out and come back with questions if you can't get it working!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is more I can add, although one answer is accepted.

There are two interfaces for Layouts: [`LayoutManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) and [`LayoutManager2`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager2.html). The second one extends the first one. So, all layout classes are inherited from `LayoutManager`.

Now, `LayoutManager2` lets you arrange your components according to some constraints. For example, in Shakedown's answer, `BorderLayout.CENTER` is a constraint for `BorderLayout`.

However, the layouts those implements only `LayoutManager` does not accept constraints for a specific component. `GridLayout` is such a layout. It will start adding components from top-left corner and continue towards right and go to next line when one line is full.

You may be interested about [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).