# GridLayout columns

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I recently decided to start using GridLayout because FlowLayout seems somewhat amateur. However, I need help. The parameters when creating the GridLayout are (rows,columns,row space,column space). I have a variable for the row amount and 4 for the column amount, but when I try to add a JButton after everything else, there are 5 columns.
Here is my code:

```
byte i = 0;
    while(i < main.componentNum)
    {
        comp[i] = new JLabel("component #" + (i+1));
        box[i] = new JComboBox();
        field[i] = new JTextField(5);
        edit[i] = new JButton("edit");

        comp[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        box[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        field[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        edit[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(comp[i]);
        add(box[i]);
        add(field[i]);
        add(edit[i]);

        i++;
    }
```

When I run the above code, I get four columns and it works fine. But when I add a button to the end, I get five. Can anyone tell me how to give one button an entire row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Docs

> One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any
>   number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.

Now, without your actual code the sets up the `GridLayout`, it's difficult to say, but, if your after maintaining only 4 columns, I would create a `GridLayout` as follows, `new GridLayout(0, 4)`

If you want something more flexible, look into `GridBagLayout`

Comment: +1 for explaining a frequently misunderstood feature. Here's a minimal [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5751044/230513).

Comment: Yes, although I figured it out before getting a reply, thank you very much. +1