# Add used JPanel to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I want to replace JPanel1 in a JFrame by JPanel2 which contains a JScrollPane on which JPanel1 should be displayed.

Making the JFrame displaying JPanel2 works, but when I use

> JPanel2.JScrollPane1.setViewportView(JPanel1)

i end up having nothing displayed on my JScrollPane1. 
However, adding other components work, e.g.:

> JPanel2.JScrollPane1.setViewportView(new JTextField("I need help!"))

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for faster help.

Comment: Also follow Java naming convention, and use lower case for variable names and follow encapsulation rules by using private fields and getters, unless you have good reason for not doing so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing: How to change GUI dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750068/java-swing-how-to-change-gui-dynamically); also consider `CardLayout`.

Comment: Yea, sorry for poor coding style - I didn't program for many years.

Comment: @trashgod I don't understand why I should be using CardLayout, as the pointer should be working... and CardLayout cannot be used here, as the parent jPanel1 should become the child of a content of jPanel2.
However, I figured out that if I reinitiate the variable (by using jPanel1 = new JPanelWithContent();) everything works fine. Do you have any idea why I have to reinitiate it instead of just passing the pointer on?

Comment: If you really can't use `CardLayout`, try the other approach cited in your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).