# Form customization for multiple customers

Tags: java, php, .net, templates, webforms

We have one project, which selling to different customers. Some customers want have some custom of form.
Abstract example, we have standart form with fields: name, description, price, ...
Another customer want same form, but another ordering fields: name, price, description.
Third customer want same form, but need add some new fields, and some logic.

What are the best ways or patterns for resolve this problem in one template?

Comment: you cannot expect the form to know the customer who he is so put some conditions where force customer to select the desired form behavior, mixing with PHP and CSS or jQuery and CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try a dynamic UI, have a setup to design their own UI to have Data input fields. Follow this question for more information to continue with a dynamic UI. [Java Swing: How to change GUI dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750068/java-swing-how-to-change-gui-dynamically)