# BorderLayout, asking user input for HGap and VGap

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I was wondering if anyone could give me any pointers on where to start with my assignment. I'm supposed to create a program that allows the user to input a value which would set the HGap or VGap between the buttons in BorderLayout. I've tried mapping it out on paper but I don't know if I should use a panel or a label, or how to implement the method of setting the gaps with a text area, or even how to extend the frame beyond the buttons (I have a code for the buttons but they fill out the entire space). This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Similarly for VGap. Any help is greatly appreciated, but have in mind that I'm only a beginner. I only need suggestions and I'll try to update you with my coding, but for now I don't have anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are even using the assigned toolkit for the project and have appropriately tagged your question.  The image in your question is a screenshot of a Swing UI, not a JavaFX UI.  If you are writing a Swing application and not a JavaFX application, please update the tags in your question to reference the appropriate technology (or you are going to end up with answers that are not applicable and confuse you).

Comment: you're right it's Swing, i got confused on that part, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: [*Java Swing: How to change GUI dynamically*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5750068/230513) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may give you an idea...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BorderDemo extends JFrame {
    private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel propertiesPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton north = new JButton("North");
    private JButton south = new JButton("South");
    private JButton west = new JButton("West");
    private JButton east = new JButton("East");
    private JButton center = new JButton("Center");
    private BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("BorderLayout Properties:");
    private JLabel hGapLabel = new JLabel("HGap:");
    private JLabel vGapLabel = new JLabel("VGap:");
    private JTextField hGapField = new JTextField();
    private JTextField vGapField = new JTextField();
    private GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 2);
    private Integer hGapInt;
    private Integer vGapInt;

    public BorderDemo() {
        buttonPanel.setLayout(border);
        buttonPanel.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        buttonPanel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        buttonPanel.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        buttonPanel.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
        buttonPanel.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
        propertiesPanel.setLayout(grid);
        propertiesPanel.add(hGapLabel);
        propertiesPanel.add(hGapField);
        propertiesPanel.add(vGapLabel);
        propertiesPanel.add(vGapField);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(propertiesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        hGapField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                hGapInt = Integer.parseInt(hGapField.getText());
                border.setHgap(hGapInt);
                setSize((int) (getWidth() + hGapInt), getHeight());
                validate();
            }
        });

        vGapField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                vGapInt = Integer.parseInt(vGapField.getText());
                border.setVgap(vGapInt);
                setSize(getWidth(), (int) (getHeight() + vGapInt));
                validate();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BorderDemo borderDemo = new BorderDemo();
        borderDemo.setVisible(true);
        borderDemo.setSize(400, 400);
        borderDemo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        borderDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this is exactly what i was looking for! i'd already given up because i had an idea but didn't know how to work with it, and this really saved me!