# adding components dynamically on the clicking of a button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       //removing existing panels


        Panel6.setLayout(null);
        JLabel label1=new JLabel("This is panel 4");
        label1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel6.add(label1);
        label1.setText("this is panel 4");
        System.out.println("here i am");
        jPanel6.revalidate();


        jPanel6.repaint();

    }
```

panel6 is already been created in design but at run time button is not being added in the panel dynamically

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code to determine what's wrong. For example, I'm not sure if/how `Panel6` and `jPanel6` relate.

Comment: You mean `jLabel` is not added?

Comment: `Panel6.setLayout(null)` is your key problem, nothing is sizing/positioning the label, and since you’ve done away with the layout manager, revalidate will do nothing. Short answer, don’t use null layouts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750068/5855946 you can see this also for  add component dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Adding components after setting `jPanel6.setLayout(null)` places them one on top of the other. (I assume JPanel6 is a typo).
When `jPanel6` is created assign a layout manager to it. For example: 
`jPanel6.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

And change `jButton1ActionPerformed` :

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JLabel label1=new JLabel("This is panel 4");
        label1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jPanel6.add(label1);
        revalidate(); //remove setSize to parent, if any
   }
```

For more information about layout managers see [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: You still need the revalidate(). This is what invokes the layout manager, otherwise the label will still have a size of (0, 0) and there will be nothing to paint.

Answer (score -3):

You have to manually define the `width` and `height` of your label if you're adding `jLabel` into `panel6` with absolute layout.

```
label1.setWidth(100);
label1.setHeight(30);
```

Comment: Or just make use of appropriate layout managers and solve all the other issues that null layouts present

Comment: @MadProgrammer some people like perfect precision. Null layout works for some.

Comment: Some people have to much time to waste on reinventing the wheel. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion

Comment: (1-) don't use a null layout. There is no reason to do so. @JacobB. `some people like perfect precision.` - so then use a layout manager. It will calculate the perfect precision every time without guess work. There is absolutely no reason to use a null layout in a question like this.

Comment: Well yeah in a question like this, I'm just saying sometimes people like to use null. Don't hate 

Comment: @JacobB., only because they don't know any better.

Comment: Well sure, but everyone had to start somewhere

Comment: So we provide answers to provide good coding practices so you don't learn bad habbits.

Comment: Here's a good example of what happens when using `null-layout`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097 @MadProgrammer might have nightmares after seeing it