# Dynamic changing of layouts in swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I  am almost certain this question was asked before here: [Java Swing: How to change GUI dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750068/java-swing-how-to-change-gui-dynamically) , but I seem to just have some fundamental misunderstanding in how it works.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JTest extends JFrame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JTest t = new JTest();
  }

  Container pane;

  public JTest()
  {
    setSize(500,500);
    setTitle("JTest");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JButton old = new JButton("old");
    old.addActionListener(new OldButton());
    pane.add(old);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(50,20));
    pane.add(scroll);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  private class OldButton implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      JButton old = new JButton("new");
      old.addActionListener(new NewButton());
      pane.add(old);
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(50,20));
      pane.add(scroll);
      pane.validate();
    }
  }

  private class NewButton implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

      pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
      JButton old = new JButton("old");
      old.addActionListener(new OldButton());
      pane.add(old);
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(50,20));
      pane.add(scroll);
      pane.validate();
    }
  }  
}
```

This code should replace the preexisting layout with a new one anytime the button in the corner is pressed, but instead, it just adds the new layout to the frame. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Adding some information. A picture for reference:

[image: picture]

I'm making a set of components like this inside the scroll pane. whenever I press the "Make new field" button, I want it to add a "field" (the name of the field followed by a textarea or some such) to the set in that scrollpane. This means changing the layout of the area inside the scrollpane to include the new field.

Comment: If all you want your button to do is to change the layout, then your ActionListener should do what trashgod recommends in  his answer: change the container's layout and then tell the layout manager to re-layout its components. He recommends that you call `validate()` on the container, but this has been changed to `revalidate()` more recently, but that's it. Why are you not doing this? And why is your ActionListener doing the other things?

Comment: If you need to change components that are shown, then use a CardLayout. If you want to change the button, then either change its text, or its ActionListener or best of all, its Action.  Please clarify **exactly** what it is you want to have happen.

Comment: @Hovercraft What I want to do exactly is create a list of components on the frame. when a button is pressed, I want to be able to add or remove an undetermined number of components to/from the frame. I'm pretty sure that requires either replacing or changing the layout, but every way I've tried just creates a weird duplicate layout.

Comment: Please enumerate more specifically what you mean by "create a list of components" because the details matter. Consider editing your question with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- so it looks like what you want to do (and please correct me if I'm wrong) is to add a new component to a JPanel that is displayed within a JScrollPane. If so, then you do not want to change or swap layouts, and you certainly don't want to keep adding new JScrollPanes. Instead consider doing:

- Create one JScrollPane and add to your GUI. Don't re-add this as you'll only need one.
- add a JPanel to the JScrollPane's viewport that uses a layout that allows multiple components to be easily added to it. Perhaps a GridLayout or a BoxLayout, depending on what you need.
- Also consider not adding the above JPanel directly to the viewport but rather adding it to another JPanel, one that uses BorderLayout, adding the first JPanel to the BorderLayout-using JPanel's BorderLayout.PAGE_START position, and then add *this* to the JScrollPane's viewport. This way the first JPanel won't stretch to fill the viewport initially.
- Then in your button's ActionListener, add your components to the first JPanel by calling `.add(...)` on it, and then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on that first JPanel to layout the newly added components and repaint the JPanel and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out this wasn't a layout problem at all. I had failed to realize that setting a new layout doesn't cause the previous layout's components to disappear, you have to remove them before adding the new components. That's why I was getting duplication.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, though.